# Read an HTML/Text file and Send it as a HTML Formated Email in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, html, wpf, email

I have a WPF application that sends out a HTML-formatted email when a button is clicked. The entire email message is in HTML-format and it does work.

However, I was wondering if there was a way to read a `html` file and send it out rather than writing the whole message in the code behind...keeping all the HTML formatting in-tact.

I tried something like this:

```
string MessageTosend = File.ReadAllText("path to txt/html file");
```

But that just sent out an email that only has text (no styling, no html...just the plain text found in the file).

Then I thought, I may have to convert everything:

```
string MessageTosend = Convert.ToString(File.ReadAllText("path to txt/html file"));
```

But that does the same thing as before.

Is there a way to do achieve this? Or will I have to stick to having

```
string MessageTosend = @"<html> ... lots of html stuff ... </html>";
```

for every button that sends an email?

For notice: The contents of the `.txt` and `.html` file I attempted to read from was tested using the same contents of the above string (which, again, works as expected), and without the double quotes (example: `width=""100""` and `width="100"`)

Comment: Did you check the source of the received email to see if it was plaintext or HTML?  Also, show the code you used to send the email. Are you ensuring `msg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html`?

Comment: @Mendhak I have `message.IsBodyHtml = true;`. Prior to attempting to send email by reading off a file, I wrote all the HTML in a string (as seen in the last line). The contents of the `.txt`/`.html` file I'm attempting to read from is the same as what was in the string before hand.

Comment: There is definitely something missing from this picture. A string is a string, so something must be different when you are loading it from a file. Try doing both solutions at the same time, and compare the two strings to ensure that they are equal. (StringComparer.CompareOrdinal)

Comment: @TroelsLarsen I compared the two and the original solution isn't the same as the txt/html file that is read (even though the content of the file is a exactly the same). If I remove the `html` tags from each solution and compare it, everything is fine and the message sends.

The `html` formatting is just not being acknowledged at all. I'm trying to get it to be acknowledged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an encoding to your file read:

```
string MessageTosend = File.ReadAllText("path to txt/html file", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Try reading a file simply containing < and compare it to the string "<". Repeat for any special characters until you find a mismatch. Then find the character number like this:

```
(int)MessageTosend[0] // < should be 60 (3C in UTF-8)
```

Find out what the offending characters are, and we may be able to help. If I read a file, I do not see this problem.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `,Encoding.UTF8` made sure the html-formatted was presented exactly as expected. Just have to make sure the files are `.html`. :)